# WPF Binding CommandParameter to Element of perent window

Tags: c#, wpf, commandparameter

I build some WPF application that as MainView, inside this MainView I have a button that opens a setting window and a Model that I want to be able to show or hide from this settings view. (the show/hide button was originally on the MainView itself) the problem is that I do not know how to use the CommandParameter in the SettingsView to bind to an element In the MainViw.

the element in the MainView:

```
        <Dev:DevUnitView x:Name="DevData" DataContext="{Binding MainModel.DevUnit}" Visibility="Visible" Margin="994,656,74,-83"/>
```

the button in the SettingsView:

```
        <Button Content="Show/Hide debug values" Command="{Binding Settings.DevVisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Dev:DevUnitView}}, Path=DataContext}" Margin="156,22,180,349"/>
```

I also tried to Bind to the MainView but I do not know how to find the element I need from there:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mainWindow:MainView}}, Path=DevUnit}"
```

in this case, it cannot resolve the "DevUnit" in the data context, I also tried by name and other variation of this without success.

the old button that worked in the MainView:

```
   <Button Content="DEV" Command="{Binding Settings.DevVisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DevData}" Margin="406,359,810,259"/>
```

now no matter how I try to bind it I getting Null UserControl.

Comment: The "old button" gets the DevUnitView as CommandParameter (by `{Binding ElementName=DevData}`), while the "button in the SettingsView" gets the `DataContext` object of an optional DevUnitView ancestor of the SettingsView. That are two totally different things. Is DevUnitView an ancestor in the visual tree of SettingsView? Why the DataContext?

Comment: @Clemens no it isn't, the MianView is an ancestor in the visual tree of SettingsView a the "DevUnitView " is bind to the MainView as DataContext.

Comment: You should try to understand that WPF is not something you can master by trying out anything that you could possibly write in XAML. Reading up on the basic concepts is essential, and can't be avoided. Neither the first nor the second CommandParameter Binding doesn't seem to make sense. If you open a new SettingsView window in code behind, you may simply set its DataContext before showing the window, e.g. like `settingsView.DataContext = somethingSensible;`. We do however not know what exactly you are trying to use as the SettingsView's DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens I want to send a view that is not inside my settingsView but on a different View, is there any reasonable way to do it?

Comment: @Clemens I also use Prism in this project if it helps